# How do I make a slider using a script in Unity/C#?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, game-development

I am very new to Unity (I have only been using it for a couple days) and I want to make a health slider for every instance of a wall in my 2d game. I do not want to have to make a slider for every single wall manually so I wanted to do it through scripting. If anyone could help me out on how to do this it'd be greatly appreciated.

All I've tried doing is making a slider by doing Slider healthBar = new Slider();, which didn't work.

Comment: If you use a base prefab and prefab variants (if you have multiple wall types), then you only need to make the "slider" once.  [Unity Manual - Prefabs](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/Prefabs.html).

Comment: Slider != Healthbar .... second is a display only, the first would imply  the user can manually adjust the value by dragging some sort of handle - which doesn'r seem to be what you are looking for ... and whyt @hijinxbassist said .. use prefabs! Change the one base prefab -> change is reflected in all prefab variants

Answer (score 0):

I have some 3D rectangles as a health slider for every enemy.

This is how I did:

1. I’ve created the cube and scaled to rectangle.
2. Make this cube a child of a empty game object with 1, 1, 1 scale.
3. Create a script that scales the wanted axis based on `currentLife / totalLife`.

In code terms, would be like:

```cs
// Even a 2D object, has 3 axis for scaling
// Replace the division to XYZ you need
father.transform.localScale = new Vector3(1, 1, (currentLife / totalLife));
```

For a better suggestion, show us what you have for health control.

Answer (score 0):

To create a health slider for every instance of a wall in your 2D game, you can follow these steps:

1. First, you need to add a Slider UI element to your game's Canvas. You can do this by right-clicking on the Canvas in the Hierarchy window and selecting "UI" -> "Slider". This will create a new Slider object in your scene.
2. Next, you need to create a script that will handle the health slider for each wall. You can do this by creating a new C# script in your project, and attaching it to each wall object in the scene.
3. In your script, you need to reference the Slider object that you created in step 1. You can do this by adding a public Slider variable to your script, and then dragging and dropping the Slider object from the Hierarchy window onto the variable in the Inspector window.

```
public Slider healthSlider;
```

4. Next, you need to add code to update the value of the health slider based on the wall's health. This will depend on how you are handling health in your game, but for example, if each wall has a "health" variable that decreases as the wall takes damage, you can update the value of the health slider like this:

```
healthSlider.value = health / maxHealth;
```

Where "health" is the current health of the wall, and "maxHealth" is the maximum health of the wall.

5. Finally, you can test your script by selecting one of the wall objects in the scene and adjusting the value of the health slider in the Inspector window.

Repeat steps 2-5 for each wall object in your scene, and each wall should now have its own health slider that updates automatically based on its current health.